# Comment system in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I write script and form for comment for my movie website but I don't know how to store each comment in his table column in database for specyfic movie.

for example,
I have to movies on this image http://prntscr.com/65wilp
So, I want when I post comment on movie 95ers Time Runners 2013 to store that comment in column for that movie, and comment for Guardians of the Galaxy 2014
in his column.

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend using disqus or livefyre or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more database tables. Learn more about relationships. You need two tables. Movie_table and comments_table. The relationships between two is 1:N.
This says, The ONE movie has a MANY comments.

Try put hidden input to the comment form named movie_id. If you list movies from Movie_table you can fill this input with a correct ID of movie row. Next, if you send the comment, you know the id of movie and you can make the relation of comment to movie (via foreign keys).

this can help you to make tables http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1tox/

and this can make you get more skills https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/database-relationships-one-to-many/

Comment: so when I add new movie to my website I need create a table for comments just for that movie?

Comment: no you have database of movies, and database comments, but you can assign movie by foreign key to comments. If you use sql query like a SELECT * FROM movies LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.movie_id = movies.id  ... you can see the result and then you can use filtering results by WHERE condition.